# Jordan-unmeasurable closed bounded subset of $R$

Tags: measure-theory

I know that such subset exists, and read somewhere that the Cantor set is an example of this (the Jordan measure is assumed). However, I couldn't find any proof to this, and really don't know if it's true or not. Could you please clarify this question?

Comment: Closed sets are measurable. They are complements of open sets and these are countable unions of intervals.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: the Jordan measure isn't countable additive (only finitely).

Comment: Urgh. I suggest you put that important piece of information that you are talking about Jordan-mesurability in a more prominent place than a parenthesis!

Comment: The [Fat Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is not Jordan Measurable.

Comment: @JacobSchlather: thanks! Would you post this as the answer?

Comment: @JacobSchlather: Am I Jordan measurable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Fat Cantor Set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set) is not Jordan measurable.